# Activate "char_classes" in boost regex library

Tags: c++, regex, boost

```
boost::wregex regex(_T("[0-9a-fA-F]+"));
boost::wsmatch match;
if (boost::regex_search(device, match, regex))
```

The above code works but if I want to replace the "0-9a-fA-F" with character class it is not clear what flag must be set.
I tried:

```
boost::wregex regex(_T("[:xdigit:]+"), boost::regex::extended);
```

It seems that the flag "no_char_classes" is set.

What must be done to activate "char_classes"?

Comment: You must use `"[[:xdigit:]]+"`

Comment: Thanks, it works.